Powershell script run from normal Powershell command line eventually hangs?
Is there a max execution time or max number of loops or sleeps in Powershell?
This script below is supposed to fetch something, print it, sleep, repeat, for hours until it's all done. But after ~5min it stops printing, i.e. hangs.
$startTime = Get-Date
$id= $args[0]
while (1) {
    $cmd = '&.\getMyDriverPercentDone.exe json ' + $id + '?'
    $JsonInfo = iex $cmd
    $Info = $JsonInfo | ConvertFrom-Json
    $percDone = [uint32]$Info.Summary.PercentDone
    Write-Output "$(Get-Date) $($percDone / 10)"
    if ($percDone -gt 1000) {
        break
    }
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
}
$dur = NEW-TIMESPAN -Start $startTime -End (Get-Date)
Write-Output "Total Time was $dur"


are you doing this inside of a job ? how can you be sure it's not getMyDriverPercentDone.exe the one hanging your script ?

It's run from a normal Powershell command line by manually typing in .\CheckPercDone.ps1. I doubt the driver communication hangs because I start another utility or I restart this utility and the communication is working fine. But yes I guess I'll add a million prints to figure out which line freezes up.

I don't think this is caused by pwsh itself, there is definitely no limit for loop iterations. If you were using recursion then yes, there would be problems but not the case here. You can also just get rid of iex. $JsonInfo = .\getMyDriverPercentDone.exe json "$id?" should work just fine

Good point re iex, @Santiago, but note that it must be "${id}?", because - incredibly - ? is a valid character in a variable name - see GitHub issue #11379.

Using more printouts I determined that it was hanging in the sleep. After removing the iex it has worked for 15min were it used to hang after 5min.

@mklement0 why is that incredible? $? predates ?. by over a decade.

@MathiasR.Jessen that's a fair point, but I should have clarified that I was referring to custom variables rather than automatic (built-in, reserved) variables such as $?. In POSIX-compatible shells, from which $? was (syntactically) borrowed, foo?='x' fails, for instance. And while $foo?='x' - counterintuitively (perhaps the better word) - succeeds in PowerShell, it is likely to trip you up not just with ?., but also in string-interpolation scenarios such as the one at hand. Also note that $$ is an automatic variable too, but $foo$='x' does not work. Ditto for ^

BTW still not working. It just hangs after 5 to 20min.

You may want to recheck the following lines:
`if ($percDone -gt 1000) {
    break
}`

If $percDone can never exceed 1000 then the script will hang. Since this variable refers to percentages, it seems plausible to me that 100 may be a more realistic value, and even then I would use the -eq operator instead of -gt.

percDone is really percDone X 10 to then be translated to xx.x% as you can see where it get divided by 10. Regardless this script stops printing anything. If the problem was the 100 then I assume the script would NOT hang. It would continue printing 100.0% done forever.
